# C Compare array elements using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make a program to compare array elements using pointers and to give me some result; I make this simple program just to test if it works but I don't know why.. if i enter equals numbers nothing happes. So the first variable of the array is ptr so ptr + 1 means the next element, if i enter directly ch[0] == ch[1] it works. After that I want to make the program to compare characters if are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch[2];
    int *ptr = &ch;
    scanf("%d%d", &ch[0], &ch[1]);
    printf("Numbers to compare %d and %d", *ptr, *ptr + 1);
    if (*ptr == *ptr + 1){
        printf("Equals numbers\n");
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: `*ptr + 1` should be `*(ptr + 1)` and `ptr=&ch;` should be `ptr=ch;`

Comment: * dereference operator is applied before the + operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember a quick rule.

If the elements are `i th` and `i+1 th` index of some array, the the way to access them without using pointer is 
`a[i]` & `a[i+1]`

Now if you want to get the address of these values without using pointer, then you do `&a[i]` and `&a[i+1]`

Now if you want to perform the above two tasks with pointer, then remember array name itself is a pointer to it. So if you want to get the address of `i th` and `i+1 th` element, the it will be simply

`(a + i)` and `(a + i + 1)`

Now if you want to get the values at these locations, then simply de-reference it like

`*(a + i)` and `*(a + i + 1)`

That's why in this case, it will be `*ptr == *(ptr + 1)`

**Note:** `&a[i] is equivalent to (a+i)`
and `a[i] is equivalent to *(a+i)`

**Note 2:** `If you are not using Turbo C in windows system, then it is not recommended to use conio.h because it is not platform independent. I recommend you to move from Turbo C & conio.h`

Answer (score 0):

To explain @kaylum comment which is correct:
You had `if (*ptr == *ptr + 1)` now the `*ptr` part is correct but the right hand side of the `==` is incorrect because the way you have it your dereferencing `ptr`  and then adding one to that value. However you want to increment `ptr` and then dereference hence why you need the `()`

Answer (score 0):

you are making mistake

> 1. int *ptr=&ch;
> 2. *ptr == *ptr + 1
> 3. printf("Numbers to compare %d and %d",*ptr,***ptr+1**);

1. replace it with `*ptr=ch` becoz `ch` is an integer array so if you assign it directly to `*ptr` it will return the first address of `ch` i.e `ch[0]` address will be return
2. difference between using `*ptr+1` and `*(ptr+1)`

   `*ptr+1` is similar to `ch[0]+1` 
    and `*(ptr+1)` is similar to `ch[1]`

[image: Explained]

3. you are doing `*ptr+1` this will increment your first position of array `ch`  so your output will Number to compare `1 and 2` even if your input is `1 and 5` replace it with `*(ptr+1)`